# Invoking Function Property Using Module Pattern

Tags: javascript, properties

In the following code I want to ask what is the difference between invoking `seqer.set_prefix = ('Q');` and `seqer.set_prefix('Q');` ?

```
var serial_maker = function ( ) {
    // Produce an object that produces unique strings. A
    // unique string is made up of two parts: a prefix
    // and a sequence number. The object comes with
    // methods for setting the prefix and sequence

    // number, and a gensym method that produces unique
    // strings.
    var prefix = '';
    var seq = 0;

    return {
            set_prefix: function (p) {
            prefix = String(p);
        },

        set_seq: function (s) {
            seq = s;
        },
        gensym: function ( ) {
                var result = prefix + seq;
                seq += 1;
                return result;
            }
        };
    };


    var seqer = serial_maker();
    seqer.set_prefix = ('Q'); // OR seqer.set_prefix('Q');
    seqer.set_seq = (1000); // OR seqer.set_seq(1000);;
    var unique = seqer.gensym(); // unique is "Q1000"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is:

```
seqer.set_prefix = ('Q');
```

replaces the `set_prefix` property with the value `'Q'`.

```
seqer.set_prefix('Q');
```

calls the `set_prefix()` method with the value `'Q'`. (Which in turn sets the value of the `prefix` variable to `'Q'`.)

The same explanation applies for your line with `set_seq`.

Comment: So in one case you are calling the desired function. In the other you are **replacing** the desired function with the value `'Q'`!